# How realistic would it be if it survived to turn into a land invertebrate? Like an Earth octopus?

Tags: biology, super-powers, survival, health

Two superheroes are fighting a battle.

The First one breaks the second one's spine, above and below, breaks the ribs, pulls out the spine, and leaves.

The Second has the ability of bio-kinesis, he can heal, can restore the circulatory system, can increase his muscle mass in seconds almost like the hulk, and can create bone plates under the skin.

The spine(spine) is too complex, the Second one can not reproduce it.

It can create neural networks.

Question:
How realistic would it be if it survived to turn into a land invertebrate?  Like an Earth octopus?

Comment: With what you've specified, everything you've said is so far from the reality of the way organisms actually work, it's unclear what you mean by "realistic". Can you edit to clarify, quite a lot.

Comment: "Two superheroes are fighting a battle." Then the answer is it's not realistic. It doesn't matter what the question is.

Comment: it'd probably be more realistic if hero 2 went into shock and died. Chances are that there was brain damage (I doubt superhero 1 was worried about damaging superhero 2's brain while *ripping his spine off his body*. I wonder if the head shouldn't have come out too Predator style?) and he was probably already bleeding to death since the chances of the broken ribs having pierced internal structures like the lungs isn't low. If he somehow survived he'd be lying on the ground with broken ribs and a massive wound where his spine should be. Chances are that some his organs are also on the floor.

Comment: Also: what in the world did superhero 2 do? Cause joker made Clark kill his wife and unborn child by accident and nuked his city, and all he got was a fist to the chest.

Comment: @ProjectApex  maybe he's a white super-straight man and he made a joke about black lesbians? ))

Comment: @g0ldenlights that sounds even worse, hero 2 was brutally murdered with obvious traces of cruelty for the crime of acting an idiot. Superhero 1 starts to make omniman sound like a chill dude.

Answer (score 2):

So, that isn't very realistic or survivable.

The spine contains the spinal cord and is connected to the central nervous system, it is also connected to the base of the skull. Ripping out a person's skeleton (besides killing them automatically), would leave them paralyzed and likely with irreparable brain damage since part of the brain stem (which is important). And without the support system of our bone structure, gravity would make an invertebrate a jello-meat-sack on land. Since the bone structure is what supports it all.

Otherwise, looking at what land invertebrates are, they could create an exo-skeleton, not unlike a spider, bee, or turn into a worm. But none are great after-fight living styles.

[image: The Central Nervous system]

The above is a diagram of the central nervous system. Just the nerves, no bones. As you can see, where the spine would be everything connects.

[image: Brain To Spinal Cord Diagram]

This diagram specifies the point where the brain meets the spinal cord.